# Как подлючиться к FlashPlayerPlugin для управления им?

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток!

Браузер Firefox при открытии flash контента (.swf) производит запуск процесса FlashPlayerPlugin*****.exe и есть приложения которые подключаются к этому процессу и позволяют выполнять действия во flash.(эмуляция нажатий на кнопки и подобное (скорее всего предварительно разбирают flash на сорцы и производят вызов необходимых функций и методов)). Вопрос в том, каким образом можно выполнить подключение к уже запущенному FlashPlayerPlugin, но с помощью С#?

Comment: чисто из интереса - зачем? флэш к концу года отомрет, думаю.

Comment: @strangeqargo, хочется сделать подобное, но самому и есть идея по применению подобной технологии для автоматизации рутинных действий

Comment: надеюсь, эта игра того стоит

Comment: @strangeqargo, да пока рано о чем то говорить т.к. не понятно, что, куда, чего и как)

Comment: а что за приложения? покажи примеры? В принципе, ты можешь открыть их в дебаггере и посмотреть, какие функции они используют, потом загуглить, как вызывать те же методы из c#